# Can't execute javascript on chrome new tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Guys im having problem in executing javascript on chrome new tab (which url is empty).
For example, i open a new tab, and i type `javascript:alert("Hello everyone!");` in the address bar and press enter, and nothing happened.

However if i head to any website such as google.com or so on, and i reenter the code `javascript:alert("Hello everyone!");` in the address bar and press enter. An alert will appeared.

Comment: I don't think the chrome html renderer and javascript engine actually run on it's new tab page, because the new tab page isn't a web page, it's just part of the chrome gui.

Comment: They do, check the developer tools ;-)

Comment: Press F12, Click Console and type 'alert("Hello World");'

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to 'solve' this as this has been done by design to prevent various forms of user centric attacks where `chrome://` scoped urls have additional permissions which could be misused (typeing javascript in the url bar and hitting enter is the same as doing an `eval` in the scope of the currently visible document (page)).

If however you only need this for yourself you can open the developer console (right click anywhere->inspect element->console) and feel free to try out any javascript there.

Comment: Just press F12 to get the console up

Comment: F12 will only bring the console up if that was the last thing you opened in the developer tools